# which is better javascript practice?

Tags: javascript, performance

**Case A**

```
    (function(){

    //this is to access this a property "PublicItem" from outside this closure
    window.PublicItem=function(){
      //codes
    }

    //internal variables
     var _varA,_varB,_varC,_varD;

    //internal functions
    function _internalFunc1(){}
    function _internalFunc2(){}
    function _internalFunc3(){}

    })();
```

**Case B**

```
    (function(){

    //this is to access this a property "PublicItem" from outside this closure
    window.PublicItem=function(){
      //codes
    }

    //this variable will hold all internal variables and methods
    var _global={};

    //internal variables to hold all other internal variables
     _global._varA="something for a";
     _global._varB="something for b";
     _global._varC="something for c";

    //internal functions
    _global._internalFunc1=function (){}
    _global._internalFunc2=function (){}
    _global._internalFunc3=function (){}  

    })();
```

The difference between two cases is in **Case A** i have created as many as variables/functions as i need. And in **case2** i have created a single variable named `_global` and for creating any internal variable/function i have made it the property of `_global`. I want you to suggest me which way is better specially in sense of memory and performance, you may comment on any other parameters too.

Comment: oops just committed a slight mistake correcting it!!

Comment: Your anonymous function expressions are syntactically wrong.  They should look like `(function () { /* ... code here ... */ })();`

Comment: @andy and @felix, just corrected it.

Comment: Btw. the second one uses "more memory", as you have one more object to store. The variables and functions are also one more level away from the calling context. But it should not make such a big difference.

Comment: @felix: what difference does it make if i have around 40 fns and and around 100 variables.

Comment: @Praveen Prasad: I'm just saying ;) And if you have so many functions and variables you should restructure your code anyway ;)

Comment: http://jsperf.com/collected-or-multiple/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

case2 will be a little slower because the interpreter has to make two steps (1: resolve the property, 2: access the value) each time it uses a variable. But the difference is insignificant. In this case, I think the case1 is preferable just because it needs less typing.

By the way, why are you calling '_global' that way? I mean, it is suppouse to hold *private* variables and functions, right? That's the reason for the underscore.

Comment: Case1 is faster in my browser (Chrome on MacOSX), but the test is no really illustrative. It only test the creation, but not the access nor the modification of the properties. You should rather test what is faster: acessing '_var' or accesing '_global._var'.

Comment: And about the name of '_global', may be '_locals' or '_private' would be a better choice. More clear.